# Error: No such container: tgd-api_redis_1

Tags: docker, redis, containers

im trying to enter my redis container with this command :

```
docker container exec -it tgd-api_redis_1 /bin/sh
```

and this

```
docker exec -it tgd-api_redis_1 /bin/sh
```

but the result is error just like the title. i run **docker ps** to show what container I have, and the container i go to is there.

thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: You have a typo in exec command. You are entering the wrong container name

Comment: i solve this by entering container with id instead name. still don't know where is the typo. thanks btw

Comment: Glad you resolved it. As per your screenshot your image name is tgd-api-redis-1 but in the screenshot you ran with image name as tgd-api_redis_1 (underscores instead of hyphens)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your container names are wrong.

Check stroke and underscore in your names!

Try the container id.

`docker exec -it 6a0285dcd25b /bin/sh`